# I can't solvebasic code form in php

Tags: php, if-statement, post, time, isset

I am new in Php world.
This is my first question ever in any form.
Please tell me what errors in my page.
When I submit the form no result came out.
Please give me any solution.

I try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15Ucddc2ksM) video.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> My page </title>``
</head>
<body>

    <p style="font-weight:bold">hello1 world</p>
    <?php

    // Restaruant open at 8
    // Restaruant from 8-11
    // Lunch from 11-4
    // closes at 4
    $launch_menu = "Nashta <br /> 
    halwa <br /> gosher <br /> ";

    $breakfast_menu = "Launch <br />
    sugar <br /> meat <br /> ";

    if(isset($_post['time'])) {
        $time = $_post['time'];

        if($time < 8 or $time >= 16 ) {
            echo "sorry, we are closed <br />" ;
        }
        else{
            echo "Hi, what would you like order <br /> ";
            if($time < 11){
                echo $breakfast_menu;
            }
            else if ($time < 16)
            {
                echo $launch_menu;
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
    What time is it? <input type='text' name='time' /> <br />
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that you have two weird `\`\`` characters in the head, right after the title. Because of the way HTML is parsed, this means the head ends there and the `\`\`` characters end up in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variables in PHP are case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). In your example, changing `$_post` to `$_POST` seems to have the desired outcome, [since the superglobal `$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) is where POST data is stored upon script execution.

You will also want to ensure that the name of the script is in fact `index.php`, since that's where the form will send the POST data to.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I change $_post to $_Post but same problem again.   this code file name is index.php. this is the only file i have.

Comment: You need to use all capitals with superglobals, so use `$_POST` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I use $_POST and solve my problem